# Can't update/upload/install/delete anything on wordpress interface

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, upgrade, file-permissions

I'm really hoping someone has a fix to this.

I recently had a site crash as a result of a wp plugin (W3 Total Cache) and had to really go through and work on getting the site back up and running. In the process I think some file permissions got switched up (and switched back as far as I know).

Here's my problem. Since this issue, I've not been able to do any of the following:

1. Upload images to media section
2. Install/update/delete any plugins
3. Update wordpress

Attempting to complete any of those actions render an error message pointing to what I would assume is a file permissions issue, but I've pretty thoroughly investigated that and toyed with the file permissions making sure my directories are writable (755 or 775 mostly, although i've messed with a lot of different combos).

Here's an example of the type of error messages I'm getting:

```
Plugin could not be deleted due to an error: Could not fully remove the plugin(s) bean-slider/bean-slider.php.


Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.4.0.2.zip…
```

Unpacking the update…

Could not create directory.

I've been all over the forums looking for a fix and found similar issues but none of those fixes have worked for me. Can anyone help me out? I'm at my whits end right now about ready to lose my mind. I've no idea what the issue is!

Comment: delete all reinstall from backups

Answer (score 0):

Could be from owner group permissions. Change your plugin directories to the Apache group.

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be due to the permission problem in your wordpress directory. execute these lines of codes in your terminal. Navigate to the Directory where you have installed WordPress.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R 
sudo usermod -a -G www-data username
```

Replace username with the username you are using like root.